# Probability distribution over space of functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, functional-calculus

Suppose I have a random signal, like electrical noise, $X(t)$ such that the value of the signal at some instant $t_0$ is a random variable with known $\mathrm{p.d.f.}$ $f_{X(t_0)}(x)$ (I take for simplicity that the probability does not depend on time nor on previous values of the signal).
With this in mind, there must exist some set $S$ of posible signals that can be generted by the random variables at each moment on time.

So my question (asuming that the previous statements are logic) is: exist a way to define/obtain a probability density distribution over that space? Such that integrating over a subset gives me the probability that I will observe a signal from that subset?

I think if exist such thing it will a functional $F[x]$ so that the probability should be calculated from a functional integral (probably difficult to compute, if not at all of course):
$$P( X \in A) = \int_A \mathcal{D}x \ F[x]  \qquad \forall A \subseteq S$$

I tried to figure out the form of $F[x]$ by multiplying $f_{X(t)}(x)$ for many diferents moments in discrete time (since are independent of each other) and then taking the limit into continumm, but I'm not sure about that, and maybe I'll post it in a separate question.

Is there a brach/field of mathematicts that deals with this type of problems?

Thanks in advance! And sorry for the bad english and the potential bad notation.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the field of stochastic processes.  I can write up a more detailed answer on creating that probability measure in the morning, but that is the topic you want to be looking at.

Comment: I see. I've made a little research before on that topic but didn't found nothing in using funcional integrals, but I suppouse it's just matter of better searching! Have any recomendarion? Anyway, if you want to, I would like to see what yo got to say about that measure. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about a measure on the space of the paths? Is $S$ a function space and $A$ a measurable set? If yes, what space and what $\sigma$-algebra would you like to use? What you are talking about in the first paragraph is the marginal distribution at $t_0$ but if you only know that you know very little about the process. Do you have an idea about the joint distribution of $(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2},..., X_{t_n})$ for arbitrary $n$ and $t_1,...,t_n\in\mathbb{R}$? Are you interested in a specific class of processes, such as diffusion processes, Levy processes, or something else?

Comment: I have a poor background in measure theory, sorry. But I think the answer is yes, that's what I'm looking for. In the first paragraph I was trying to say that I know the distribution for all times, saying that at some $t_0$ the pdf will have that form, that was my bad. I'm not interested in a specific class, my question was more about a generic way to calculate that kind of proceses on continuous time with functionals.