# Obtaining probability density functional for a space of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

This a question related to this [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734879/probability-distribution-over-space-of-functions). Here I have a question about my attempt to find such functional:

Consider a real interval $T \subset \mathbb{R}$, interpreted like a time interval $(t_0, \ t_f)$. And consider a random signal $X(t)$ such that, $X(t_*)$ is a random variable with a known probability density function $f_{X(t_*)}(x)$ for every $t_* \in T$. The p.d.f does not depend on time nor previus values of the signal i.e. $X(t_1), X(t_2)$ are independent for every $t_1 \neq t_2$.

Now I considered the situation in which I have discrete values of time $t_n = t_0 + n\Delta t$ so the total p.d.f. will be:
$$ f_X \big( x_0,x_1, ... x_f \big) dx_0dx_1...dx_f = [f_{X(t_0)}(x_0)dx_0][f_{X(t_1)}(x_1)dx_1]... = \\ = \prod_n f_{X(t_n)}(x_n) dx_n = \prod_n f_{X(t_n)}(x_n) \ \prod_n dx_n$$
With $x_n = x(t_n)$

I manipulated the first product in this way:
$$ \prod_n f_{X(t_n)}(x_n) = e^{\ln \big[ \prod_n f_{X(t_n)}(x_n) \big]} = e^{\sum_n \ln[f_{X(t_n)}(x_n)]} \tag{1} $$

I expect that for taking $\Delta t \to 0$ (with $t_0, t_f$ fixed) the exponent in $(1)$ converges to an integral so I'll have:
$$ \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sum_n \ln[f_{X(t_n)}(x_n)]  = G[x(t)]$$
And
$$ \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\prod_n dx_n = \mathcal{D}x(t) $$

And with this results, I can calculate probabilities:

$$ P( X \in A) = \int_A \mathcal{D}x \ F[x] $$

So, Is this aproach correct? What should be the form of $G[x(t)]$? I'm pretty new in this kind of topics, so any comment will be apprecieated.

I guesed that $G[x(t)] = \int_T \ln [f_{X(t)}(x(t))] dt $ but I'm not sure, since, for instance that quantity is not adimensional. And additionaly the sum does not have a factor $\Delta t$ like in a Riemann sum.

Thanks!

Comment: Measurability issues will arise if you have an uncountable family of independent random variables, making it hard to talk about "sample paths". It is not impossible, but this is a very advanced topic in probability theory. I wonder why you want the process to have no correlations at all - almost all conceivable applications of stochastic processes need dependence which will somehow lead to "nice" sample paths such as continuous or at least càdlàg. Nice theory exists for diffusions, look at Girsanov's theorem which gives you an expression of the law of the process wrt. Wiener measure, and the..

Comment: ..Onsager-Machlup functional.

Comment: I see. The process I used have no correlation because I think it will be the simplest way to starting with this kind of topics, and later increasing complexity. Maybe this is pretty much difficult to the background I have, so recomendations are more than welcome.

Comment: Processes without correlation are pretty badly behaved. It's easier to start with diffusion processes which have continuous sample paths. So they induce a measure on spaces of continuous functions which gives rigorous meaning to what you are alluding to.

Comment: I understand your point. I think I'll start looking for that, if you have any more reference topics will be appreciated!

Comment: I think a good starting point is to become familiar with the Wiener process and then Wiener space and Wiener measure. Then, regarding Wiener measure as a kind of standard measure on the Wiener space, similar to how Lebesgue measure is the standard measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, one can express the density of the law of a Wiener process with drift wrt. to Wiener measure using a discretization similar to the one in the question.

Comment: All right, thanks!